# React how to prevent a parent's onclick event from firing when a child is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set the `onClick` prop on my div which will navigate to a new page when clicked. `svg` is absolutely positioned. How do I avoid the click event on the `svg` element?

I've already tried `stopPropagation()` but it doesn't work.

```
<div
  className={classes.container}
  onClick={() => navigate(`${props.productName}`)}
>
  <img src={props.image} alt="" />
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the obvious answer would be to put it outside of the `div`.
But if you really can't, you can always use CSS for this.

Try using [`pointer-events`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp)

**Example:**

HTML -

```html
<div
  className={classes.container}
  onClick={() => navigate(`${props.productName}`)}
>
  <img src={props.image} alt="" />
  <svg className='no-events'></svg>
</div>
```

CSS -

```css
.no-events {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but its not working :(

Comment: This is really strange. Both this method and `stopPropagation` should work. Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: it somehow works now!!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if `e.target === e.currentTarget`.

```js
function Example() {
  
  function handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
      console.log('Only container clicked');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <button>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
#react { padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0;}
.container { border: 5px solid white; padding: 1em; background-color: lightblue; }
div:hover { border: 5px solid cornflowerblue;  }
div:hover, button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: thank you. the div caused the event, i dont want the parent firing on child element;(

Comment: @CZ answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by doing these.

1. Check for the target element tag when event is triggered.
2. Assign Id's to the elements and execute your code based on the Id.
3. Use CSS pointer-events to disable pointer events of that element.